# Stored Procedure Tuning Help

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, availability-groups, performance-tuning

Actual plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJviG_y1h

I'm looking for advice on where to start with tuning the above stored procedure. We need it to complete in as near to 1 second as possible but currently taking up to 40 seconds in production. The SP seems to be fluctuating based on server workload so need it to run as efficiently as possible. Under no load in UAT against a copy of the same db it runs in 5 seconds.

The warnings from Brent Ozar's sp_blitzcache are:
Parallel, Plan Warnings, Parameter Sniffing, Implicit Conversions, Function Join, Trivial Plans, Unused Memory Grant, Plan created last 4hrs, Many Rows Table Spool, non-SARGables

This is running on the **primary** replica of an Always On Availability Group DB (2 node setup with synchronous commit and read only enabled on secondary). We cannot create any additional indexes.

**SQL version is:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU29) (KB5010786) - 14.0.3436.1 (X64)
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Other configurations of note:

- SQL Max memory is set at 92gb
- Server has 8 CPUs (all on 1 numa node)
- CTFP is set at 50
- MAXDOP set at 4
- Primary DB has RCSI enabled

Answer (score 5):

**The Potential Problem**

At a quick glance at the execution plan and what the code is doing, it looks like one of the main issues is your `JOIN` clause to `[maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi`:

```
LEFT JOIN [maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi alt 
  ON cp.id = alt.id 
  AND alt.lkp_c_ty = CASE @SourceSystem WHEN 'Rio' THEN 6942 
             WHEN 'Trakcare' THEN 6999
             END
```

Specifically the `CASE` statement, it overcomplicates the predicate, which appears to result in multiple index scans against a *larger* (+1 million rows) table.

---

**One Possible Fix**

One potential way to fix that, is by branching the code on the `@SourceSystem` variable, since this is a stored procedure anyway. Prior to your main query that joins in `[maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi`, you can create the following branch to materialize the data to a temp table:

```
-- Don't use SELECT *, list out the columns explicitly instead. I'm only doing it because I don't have your table schema to reference
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #core_patient_c_identifi;
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO #core_patient_c_identifi
FROM [maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi;

IF (@SourceSystem = `Rio`)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #core_patient_c_identifi
    SELECT *
    FROM [maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi
    WHERE alt.lkp_c_ty = 6942
END
ELSE IF (@SourceSystem = `Trakcare`)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #core_patient_c_identifi
    SELECT *
    FROM [maxims_prod].[dbo].core_patient_c_identifi
    WHERE alt.lkp_c_ty = 6999
END
```

Then your `JOIN` clause in your main query just needs to be:

```
LEFT JOIN #core_patient_c_identifi alt
    ON cp.id = alt.id
```

---

**Another Dangerous Predicate**

At the very end of your query you have the following predicate:

```
WHERE AlternativeLocalPtId = '' -- return all rows if no 3a match is found
    OR AlternativeLocalPtId = Matched_LocalPtId
```

This is potentially problematic for two reasons. The first being `OR`s can also jam up predicates from being optimally seeked on. Although this one is not overly complicated, so is probably of less concern.

The bigger issue is the `AlternativeLocalPtId` column is an alias in you previous subquery for an inline correlated subquery with an XML parsing expression. This makes the aforementioned predicate more complex than the words I just used to describe it:

```
(
    (SELECT
         CASE WHEN Match_type LIKE '%3a%' 
             THEN Matched_LocalPtId END [text()]
     FROM #MATCHED_RESULT MATCHTYPE2
     WHERE MATCHTYPE.MessageControlID  = MATCHTYPE2.MessageControlID    
     ORDER BY Match_type
     FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(200)')
) AlternativeLocalPtId
```

---

**Possible Fix**

Materialization is likely your friend again here. You can extract only the pertinent parts of the query (might be the whole main query itself) to build the expression for `AlternativeLocalPtId`, and insert it into a temp table. Then filter on the temp table by the materialized column `AlternativeLocalPtId`.

I tried to write out a code example of that solution but the query is too verbose for me to peel back and modify on here (I write my answers from my phone). But you should get the idea at this point.